# How to exclude some content from _LyoutView being added to specific view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have such script on my _LyoutView:

```
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/Noscript">
</noscript>
```

But when user with javascript disabled redirected to that page, the infinity request of that page taking place because that page contains this code above as well.

So i just thought may be there is some things out of the box in ASP.NET MVC that can help?

Basically i want that that code from _LyoutView to be added to all views except Noscript view.

i can go like that on _LyoutView:

```
@if (ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue != "Noscript")
{ 
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/Noscript">
</noscript>
}
```

But may be there is more better way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `RawUrl` property of the `Request` object to see if it contains the term "Noscript" which I'm assuming won't be part of the URL unless we're on that page.

```
@if(!Request.RawUrl.Contains("Noscript"))
{
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/Noscript">
</noscript>
}
```